# GCM Notification work slow in some time

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

> I have successfully implemented GCM in my application and its working fine.
>         I followed this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rmzv716SYkQ to integrate 
>         GCM.

The Problem is,

> When the network is speed,response from GCM is rapid.But the Internet low 
>         coverages area it gets delay to post notification.I had checked GCM in low 
>         internet area and it sends notification after 2 days.So i have to overcome 
>         from this problem.

I need clarification on,

- Is GCM works with related to internet speed?
- How facebook and twitter notification process works?
- How to improve GCM notification speed?

hope i will get answer.Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can get ride on GCM server... only Google can fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is GCM works with related to internet speed?

```
Yes, it totally depends on the server when it sends notification.
```

How facebook and twitter notification process works?

> That totally depends on their server, They might be having some better algo or better hardware .

How to improve GCM notification speed?

> You cannot control the speed of server which is not yours, only google developers can fix this.